# http2 plugin doesn't work with summary report

Tags: jmeter, http2

I have using http2 plugin to test my project. But I don't know how to config the Summary Report to get data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you install [HTTP/2 Sampler](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin) plugin using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) you get `View Result Tree Http2` listener as well:

[image]

If you add it to your Test Plan you will be able to see request and response details:

[image]

The same listener can be used for storing the data into CSV or XML file for later analysis.

Other JMeter Listeners will not be able to catch HTTP2 samplers due to their asynchronous nature which is not in line with JMeter's thread model.

More information: [The New HTTP/2 Plugin for JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-http2-plugin-for-jmeter-the-complete-guide)